# Cycle through data in the entry form as you click on the spin buttons

Tags: excel, vba

One feature I cannot get working is the up down buttons. These are supposed to allow the data in the entry form to be changed as you press them populating the form with the new lines data. This feature is linked to the search feature. Search allows you to type a word in the search box and references the Owner or Account column depending on which is selected from the dropdown. Once searched, I want the data from the found data to be loaded to the form and the line in the listbox to be highlighted. If there are multiple entries with the same name as that searched for I want to be able to scroll up and down the listbox to find the right one using the buttons. Each scroll will rewrite the info from the listbox into the form.
If no data is entered into the search box or no owner searched for or when the Launch Form button is pressed and the form is displayed then I would like to have the first entry of the listbox highlighted and entered into the form and then for the up down to scroll through the listbox and repopulate the form with each change.

I'm also aware that my update button isn't working either. If I search by owner the form is updated but if I change or enter new data and then press update the new information is not added to the data in the sheet. If I search by Account and change the data in the form and then press update it updates the record but changes the data for all entries in the listbox that have returned the same info as in the search box rather than just the line in the listbox that I want changed.

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''UserForm Activation'''''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
        cmbCategory.List = Array("Bank", "Consultancy", "Council", "EMail", "Family Tree", "Guiding", "Health", "Insurance", "Other", "PC", "Phone", "Shares", "Shop", "Shopping", "Social Media", "Sky", "Travel", "Utility", "Web")
        cmbOwner.List = Array("David", "Karen", "Lisa", "Christopher")
        cmbSearchBy.List = Array("Owner", "Account")
        
        Call Refresh_data

End Sub

'''====================Reset Function (Clear Boxes)=================================

Function Reset()
        Dim ctl As Control
        For Each ctl In Me.Controls
            Select Case TypeName(ctl)
                   Case "TextBox"
                        ctl.Value = ""
                   Case "ComboBox"
                        ctl.ListIndex = -1
            End Select
         Next ctl
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''Save Button'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet")
        Dim lr As Long
        lr = Sheets("Worksheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
'''''''''''''''Validation'''''''''
        If Me.txtAccount.Value = "" Then
           MsgBox "Please enter the Account name", vbCritical
           Exit Sub
        End If
        
        If Me.cmbCategory.Value = "" Then
           MsgBox "Please enter the correct Category from Drop Down List"
           Exit Sub
        End If

'''''''''''''''''Add Data in Excel Sheet'''''''''''''
        If MsgBox("Do you want to add the data?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Question") = vbNo Then
           Exit Sub
        End If
       With sh
            .Cells(lr + 1, "A").Value = Me.cmbCategory.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "B").Value = Me.cmbOwner.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "C").Value = Me.txtAccount.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "D").Value = Me.txtWebsite.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "E").Value = Me.txtACCDetail.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "F").Value = Me.txtLogin.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "G").Value = Me.txtPassword.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "H").Value = Me.txtPIN.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "I").Value = Me.txtMemWord.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "J").Value = Me.txtEMail.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "K").Value = Me.txtExtra.Value
            .Cells(lr + 1, "L").Value = Me.txtNotes.Value
       End With

''''''''''''''''Clear Boxes''''''''''''''''

        Call Reset
        
        Call Sort
        
        Call Refresh_data
        
        MsgBox "Detail has been added in the Worksheet", vbInformation
        
End Sub

'''''''''''''''''''Sort Data in Workbook after save or update''''''''''''
Sub Sort()
Range("A6:L500").Sort Key1:=Range("A7"), _
                     Order1:=xlAscending, _
                     Key2:=Range("C7"), _
                     Order1:=xlAscending, _
                     Key3:=Range("C7"), _
                     Order1:=xlAscending, _
                     Header:=xlYes

End Sub

'''''''''''''''''''Display Data in the Listbox''''''''''''''

Sub Refresh_data()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet")
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Sheets("Worksheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If lr = 6 Then lr = 7
    
    With Me.ListBox
         .ColumnCount = 12
         .ColumnHeads = True
         .ColumnWidths = "70,70,120,120,150,120,70,60,80,120,100,200"
         .RowSource = "Worksheet!A7:L" & lr
    End With
End Sub

'''''''''''''''''Reset Button'''''''''''''''''''

Private Sub cmdReset_Click()
        If MsgBox("Do you want to Reset the data?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Question") = vbYes Then
           Call Reset
        End If
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''Exit Button'''''''''''''''''''''

Private Sub cmdExit_Click()
        If MsgBox("Do you want to exit this form?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Confirmation") = vbYes Then
           Unload Me
        End If
End Sub

'''''''''''''''''''''''''SearchButton''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet")
        
        Dim lr As Long
        lr = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim i As Long
        
        If cmbSearchBy = "" Or Me.txtSearch = "" Then
           MsgBox "Please add item & criteria!!!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
           Exit Sub
        End If
        
        If cmbSearchBy.Value = "Owner" Then
           If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("B7:B99999"), Me.txtSearch.Text) = 0 Then
              MsgBox "No match found!!!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
              Me.txtSearch.Value = ""
              Exit Sub
           End If
           For i = 7 To lr
            If sh.Cells(i, "B").Value = Me.txtSearch.Text Then
               cmbCategory = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "A").Value
               cmbOwner = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "B").Value
               txtAccount = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "C").Value
               txtWebsite = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "D").Value
               txtACCDetail = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "E").Value
               txtLogin = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "F").Value
               txtPassword = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "G").Value
               txtPIN = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "H").Value
               txtMemWord = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "I").Value
               txtEMail = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "J").Value
               txtExtra = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "K").Value
               txtNotes = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "L").Value
            End If
        Next i
        
        
        End If
        
        
  
        If cmbSearchBy.Value = "Account" Then
           If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("C7:C99999"), Me.txtSearch.Text) = 0 Then
              MsgBox "No match found!!!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
              Me.txtSearch.Value = ""
              Exit Sub
           End If
           For i = 7 To lr
            If sh.Cells(i, "C").Value = Me.txtSearch.Text Then
               cmbCategory = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "A").Value
               cmbOwner = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "B").Value
               txtAccount = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "C").Value
               txtWebsite = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "D").Value
               txtACCDetail = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "E").Value
               txtLogin = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "F").Value
               txtPassword = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "G").Value
               txtPIN = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "H").Value
               txtMemWord = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "I").Value
               txtEMail = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "J").Value
               txtExtra = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "K").Value
               txtNotes = Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(i, "L").Value
            End If
        Next i
        End If
        
        ''If txtSearch.Text = Me.ListBox.Column(2) Then
          '' ListBox(2).Selected
        ''End If
        
End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''Update Button'''''''''''''''

Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
        Dim x As Long
        Dim y As Long
        x = Sheets("Worksheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         
        '''''''''''''''Validation'''''''''
        
        If Me.txtAccount.Value = "" Then
           MsgBox "Please enter the Account name", vbCritical
           Exit Sub
        End If
        
        If Me.cmbCategory.Value = "" Then
           MsgBox "Please enter the correct Category from Drop Down List"
           Exit Sub
        End If

'''''''''''''''''Add update in Excel Sheet'''''''''''''
        If MsgBox("Do you want to add the data?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Question") = vbNo Then
           Exit Sub
        End If
        For y = 7 To x
            If Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(y, 3).Value = txtSearch.Text Then
               Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(y, 1).Value = cmbCategory
               Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(y, 2).Value = cmbOwner
               Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(y, 3).Value = txtAccount
               Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(y, 4).Value = txtWebsite
               Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(y, 5).Value = txtACCDetail
               Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(y, 6).Value = txtLogin
               Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(y, 7).Value = txtPassword
               Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(y, 8).Value = txtPIN
               Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(y, 9).Value = txtMemWord
               Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(y, 10).Value = txtEMail
               Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(y, 11).Value = txtExtra
               Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(y, 12).Value = txtNotes
            End If
        Next y
        
        ''''''''''''''''Clear Boxes''''''''''''''''

        Call Reset
        
        Call Sort
        
        Call Refresh_data
        
        MsgBox "Detail has been updated in the Worksheet", vbInformation
        cmbCategory.SetFocus

End Sub

''''''''''''''''Delete Button'''''''''''''''

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
        Dim x As Long
        Dim y As Long
        x = Sheets("Worksheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        If Me.txtSearch = "" Then
           MsgBox "Search text can't be empty?"
           Exit Sub
        End If
        
        If MsgBox("Do you want to delete the data?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Question") = vbNo Then
           Exit Sub
        End If

        For y = 7 To x
            If Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(y, "B").Value = txtSearch.Text Or Sheets("Worksheet").Cells(y, "C").Value = txtSearch.Text Then
               Rows(y).Delete
            End If
        Next y

        Call Reset
        Call Refresh_data
        ''Unload Me
        ''UserForm.Show
        MsgBox "Data has been deleted from the Worksheet", vbInformation
    
End Sub

'''''''''''''''''' List Box Code'''''''''''''''

Private Sub ListBox_Change()
        txtSearch = Me.ListBox.Column(2)
        
        cmbCategory.Text = Me.ListBox.Column(0)
        cmbOwner.Text = Me.ListBox.Column(1)
        txtAccount.Text = Me.ListBox.Column(2)
        txtWebsite.Text = Me.ListBox.Column(3)
        txtACCDetail.Text = Me.ListBox.Column(4)
        txtLogin.Text = Me.ListBox.Column(5)
        txtPassword.Text = Me.ListBox.Column(6)
        txtPIN.Text = Me.ListBox.Column(7)
        txtMemWord.Text = Me.ListBox.Column(8)
        txtEMail.Text = Me.ListBox.Column(9)
        txtExtra.Text = Me.ListBox.Column(10)
        txtNotes.Text = Me.ListBox.Column(11)
End Sub
```

It should logically be simple enough but I'm a bit stumped from my lack of VBA knowledge!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting huge assistance for complex code and I believe this is out of bounds for help. But, regarding SpinButton, I comment that the following procedure is very common:

1. In 'Design Time' you set the Max and Min values of the SpinButton to 1 and -1 respectively, and that's it.
2. In the code, in the SpinButton's Change event, evaluate the value passed by it and proceed accordingly. As a last command, reset the SpinButton value to 0. Thus, only 1 or -1 will be read, with each new click on one of its buttons. To look:

---

```
If Me.SpinButton1.Value = -1 Then
    'user clicked down button
    'code here
    Me.SpinButton1.Value = 0
ElseIf Me.SpinButton1.Value = 1 Then
    'user clicked up button
    'another code here
    Me.SpinButton1.Value = 0
End If
```

Comment: Tried to format the code (CTRL+K), but unsuccessfully (Firefox & Chrome)

Comment: I find putting a solid line (using 4 "-" signs) above the code allows you to format the code when it's playing up like that. :)

Comment: Well this is a good trick, thanks. The other post I made on another (new) question, worked flawless. Maybe a temporarily fail at server side.

Comment: Plenty of Help on code formatting (including language tagging) to be found from the  **Help** button in the answer editing widget...   https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code